# Is CakePHP 3 CsrfProtectionMiddleware automatic?

Tags: cakephp, middleware, csrf-protection, cakephp-3.x

I'm in the process of rewriting an application to use most of CakePHP 3.5's features in general. However, one thing is stumping me. I have the CsrfProtectionMiddleware set up as described, and can see the token in the forms generated.

The cookbook, however, does not describe a method of "checking" the request data sent. It seemingly only states how to set things up:

```
$csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware();
$middlewareQueue
    // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
    // and make an error page/response
    ->add(ErrorHandlerMiddleware::class)

    // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
    ->add(AssetMiddleware::class)

    // Add routing middleware.
    ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))
    ->add($cookies)
    ->add($csrf);
```

When a request is received, is the check performed by CakePHP 3.5 automatically when csrf is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the check is performed automatically. Quote from the API docs:

> This middleware adds a CSRF token to a cookie. The cookie value is
>   compared to request data, or the X-CSRF-Token header on each PATCH,
>   POST, PUT, or DELETE request.
>
> If the request data is missing or does not match the cookie data, an
>   InvalidCsrfTokenException will be raised.

**https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.Middleware.CsrfProtectionMiddleware.html**

Comment: Thank you. The whole middle-ware addition has been somewhat confusing, but I think I am starting to understand it.